# Using a model in my _layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a _layout page that has a viewmodel and razor declaration like below

```
@using System.Globalization
@using Mvc4WebRole.Models
@model HomeViewModel
```

and a section on this page @sidebar using this HomeViewModel

After this codes some of my views are using other ViewModels like ProductDetailView below

```
@model Mvc4WebRole.Models.PrdcDetailViewModel
```

However I want to rebuild the project while redirected ProductDetailView it is giving me an error about ViewModel requirements like this:

[image]

Is there any reason? I have researched this error but they all telling me that you shouldnt be use IEnumerable declaration when needed uniq entity. This is not my case.

Comment: @tereško please try to fix more than just the `asp.net-mvc` tag.

Comment: Remove the @model declaration from your _layout.cshtml and only use it in your strongly typed views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not strongly type your layout page.

Remove `@model HomeViewMode` from your _layout.cshtml file.

The only place where you should bind model to your views is in your view files. If your side bar uses this model, render it as a partial view, which can use its own model.

After you have removed the HomeviewModel from your layout, you might need to add it to the views which use it, but do not have this line yet.

Comment: Thanks Serv yes i need it for the sidebar content, i will try to use partial view

Answer (score 1):

The _layout.cshtml file is kind of a "Master page", not a view, so you should not have a model declared. Everything that is dynamic, should be put in views, and if you need something dynamic in the _layout view, you should use ViewBag or some simular object/container.